# Как увеличить все значения колонки на 2%?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Нужно повысить "Стоимость" на 2% у всей таблицы Авто. Но как бы я не пытался, выдавало либо ошибку, либо пустой кортеж.

[image: Таблица Авто]

```
sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("Autosalon.db")
cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

sqlite_select_query = """UPDATE Авто SET Стоимость = Стоимость * 1.02"""
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
sqlite_select_query.commit()

cursor.close()
sqlite_connection.close()
```

Comment: Поставил, что ответ был полезен

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как увеличить стоимость на 2% в БД? SQLite3 python3 (продолжение)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1259461/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-2-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-sqlite3-python3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Autosalon.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """UPDATE Авто SET Стоимость = Стоимость * 1.02"""
cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку - sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.

Comment: @OverNiko, это предупреждение, а не ошибка. Уберите точку с запятой в конце

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: @OverNiko, не можете перевести ошибку? ;)

Comment: объект 'str' не имеет атрибута 'commit'

Comment: Вот только это не дало понимание ситуации (╯︵╰,)

Comment: Я передал запрос напрямую в cursor.execute, всё прошло, но данные не изменились

Comment: я вам уже весь код целиком в ответе привел )

Comment: У меня точно так-же но всё то-же самое - объект 'str' не имеет атрибута 'commit' , может это из за того, что он расположен в условии, а условие в функции ?

Comment: вы запускаете свой код, вместо того, который я привел вам в ответе

Comment: Код идентичен, только название переменных разное и место его вызова

Comment: ну так в том и проблема, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `.commit()` от переменной, содержащей строку. Я вам расписал весь ответ - если не хотите им пользоваться, то зачем было спрашивать?

Comment: Пойдёмте, создам новую тему )