# Как увеличить стоимость на 2% в БД? SQLite3 python3 (продолжение)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

В БД Autosalon.db нужно повысить "Стоимость" на 2% у всей таблицы Авто внутри функции up_prise_avto, но как бы я не пытался выдавало либо ошибку, либо пустой кортеж.

[image: Autosalon.db - Авто]

```
def up_prise_avto(self):

    result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Повышение", "Вы точно хотите повысить цену ?",
                                            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)

    if result == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes: 
        
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("Autosalon.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

        sqlite_select_query = """UPDATE Авто SET Стоимость = Стоимость * 1.02"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        sqlite_select_query.commit()

        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Повышение", "Цена повышена!")
    else: 
        print("No")
```

Comment: Не задавайте один и тот же вопрос, а дополняйте прежний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы вызываете метод `.commit()` от строки `sqlite_select_query` вместо того, чтобы вызывать его от объекта `sqlite_connection`:

```
...
sqlite_connection.commit()
...
```